# Spring boot custom login: "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement custom login with spring security. So I added below maven dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And my Security Config class

```
package it.mine.my.web.config;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/login" )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl( "/process" )
                .loginPage( "/login" )
                .usernameParameter( "username" )
                .passwordParameter( "password" )
                .defaultSuccessUrl( "/test", true )
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Then I created a LoginController as below.

```
package it.mine.my.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Locale;

@Controller
public class LoginController
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login( @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value = "successMsg", required = false) String success, Model model, Locale loale )
    {
        model.addAttribute( "error", error != null );
        model.addAttribute( "errorMsg", error );

        model.addAttribute( "success", success != null );
        model.addAttribute( "successMsg", success );

        model.addAttribute( "locale", loale.getLanguage() );

        return "login";
    }

}
```

Project structure

[image]

Once run this application and hit http://localhost:8080/login in browser it prompt following error.

IntellijIDEA console says,

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thank You!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from the Thymeleaf.
It is telling you that it cannot find "login" page in the "templates" directory.

[image]

Also check if page has correct configuration:

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: Was there a resolution on this? I am seeing the same exception, login.html is in the templates folder, and Thymeleaf is constantly showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

AlieneilA is right.
I had the same problem. As error message suggests, it is Thymeleaf's error. So to make it work, you can use the template in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html.
This is the official documentation, up to date, and at the end of the page you can see a simple implementation of a custom login page (luckily it's Thymeleaf template in the example).

Just follow the example in documentation